# What is the ocsi attribute?

Tags: html, exchange-server

I am looking at mail messages in my Exchange account, and I see many with the following body element declaration:

```
<body ocsi="x">
```

What is this attribute supposed to mean?

Comment: Intriguing -- it's certainly not easy to find information on.  Google's results are mostly indexed e-mails.  Could you post the full XML with your personal information removed?  Looking at the schemas might help track down an answer.

Comment: There is no schema to speak of. HTML looks pretty normal: header with title and some inline styles, the body tag with the ocsi attribute, followed by pretty regular HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to stand for either "Object-Oriented Client/Server Internet" or "Open Collaboration Services Initiative".

Comment: Thanks! I suspect neither is particularly likely as the former seems to have little to do with messaging, and the latter is linux desktop driven.